# Why are arguments handled by type-graphql always coming through as undefined

Tags: graphql, typegraphql

I am seeing some really unusual behaviour in a type-graphql project.

I've followed the documentation here https://typegraphql.com/docs/resolvers.html to link some GQL into a JS function, but the object is simply empty when it enters the function. Really not sure why it is doing this.

Given this type class:

```
@ArgsType()
export class GetFoosArgs implements IGetFoosArgs {
  @Field(() => Boolean, { nullable: true, defaultValue: false })
  bar?: boolean;

  @Field(() => Int, { nullable: true, defaultValue: 0 })
  baz?: number;

  @Field(() => Int, { nullable: true, defaultValue: 100 })
  buzz?: number;
}
```

And this query function:

```
@Query(_returns => [Foo], { name: 'foo' })
async getFoos(@Args() {
    bar,
    baz,
    buzz
}: GetFoosArgs): Promise<Foo[]> {
console.log({
    foo,
    baz,
    buzz,
});
}
```

And this GQL query:

```
{
  foos(
    bar:true,
    baz:1,
    buzz:2,
  ) {
    _key
    }
}
```

The console dump just shows:

```
  {
    bar: undefined,
    baz: undefined,
    buzz: undefined
  }
```

:-S

Comment: Are you by chance also using GraphQL-Modules?

Answer (score 1):

look good to me, I tested it and it worked just fine, maybe it's something related to your TypeGraphql typescipt setup, it might be helpful to check TypeGraphql ts config docs.

An issue I noticed and might be related is that when I use babel to compile TypeGraphql project, object destructuring in `@Args` and `@Arg` will not work properly

so maybe trying this instead might work in your case

```js
@Query((returns) => Boolean, { name: 'foo' })
async getFoos(@Args() args: GetFoosArgs): Promise<boolean> {
    console.log(args);
    return true;
}
```

The strange thing is that graphql is strict and the idea that your resolver compiled successfully then you could run the query without errors, yet you get this output is a bit confusing so I'm not sure if SO will be helpful in your case, at least not without more info.

also note that your posted code contains some errors like query using `foos` when it should be `foo` so please read how to include [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your question which will be more helpful for others to debug the issue.

P.S. I'm using TypeGraphql v0.17.6

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've installed the `babel-plugin-transform-typescript-metadata` package via npm ([enter link description here](https://github.com/leonardfactory/babel-plugin-transform-typescript-metadata#readme).

You can read more about Babel + TypeScript compiler options [here](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-plugin-transform-typescript.html#typescript-compiler-options).

In my case, the args never showed up in my emitted schema in the first place (I checked via `emitSchemaFile` option for `buildSchema`). Installing the mentioned plugin and adding it to the `plugins` section of my `.babelrc` fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, not completely sure of the nature of the problem, but I've changed things up a bit and the magic is working now.

The key thing to note is that before, I was using the `Arg` decorator from `type-graphql`, and now I'm using the `Args` decorator from `@nestjs/graphql`.

Old code:

```
import { InputType, Field, Int, Arg, ID } from 'type-graphql';

@Query(_returns => [Intent], { name: 'intents' })
    async getIntents(
        @Arg('getIntentsArgs', () => GetIntentsArgs, {
            nullable: true,
            defaultValue: {},
        })
        getIntentsArgs: GetIntentsArgs,
    ): Promise<Intent[]> {
}

@InputType()
export class GetIntentsArgs implements IGetIntentsArgs {
    @Field(() => Boolean, { nullable: true, defaultValue: false })
    displayTest?: boolean;

    @Field(() => Int, { nullable: true, defaultValue: 0 })
    skip?: number;

    @Field(() => Int, { nullable: true, defaultValue: 100 })
    take?: number;

    @Field(() => String, { nullable: true, defaultValue: 'intent._key' })
    sortColumn?: string;

    @Field(() => String, { nullable: true, defaultValue: 'asc' })
    sortDirection?: string;

    @Field(() => [Filter], { nullable: true, defaultValue: [] })
    filters?: IFilter[];
}
```

New code:

```
import {
    Resolver,
    Query,
    Parent,
    ResolveProperty,
    Mutation,
    Args,
    Context,
} from '@nestjs/graphql';

@Query(_returns => [Intent], { name: 'intents' })
    async getIntents(
        @Args({ name: 'getIntentsArgs', type: () => GetIntentsArgs }) 
getIntentsArgs: GetIntentsArgs,
    ): Promise<Intent[]> {
        return this.intentsService.getIntents(getIntentsArgs);
}

@InputType()
export class GetIntentsArgs implements IGetIntentsArgs {
    @Field()
    @IsBoolean()
    @IsOptional()
    displayTest?: boolean = false;

    @Field()
    @IsNumberString()
    @IsOptional()
    skip?: number = 0;

    @Field()
    @IsNumberString()
    @IsOptional()
    take?: number = 100;

    @Field()
    @IsString()
    @IsOptional()
    sortColumn?: string = 'intent._key';

    @Field()
    @IsString()
    @IsOptional()
    sortDirection?: string = 'asc';
    
    @Field(_ => [Filter])
    @Type(_ => Filter)
    @IsOptional()
    filters?: Filter[] = [];
    Filter[] = [];
}
```